# how to limit my input with only some numbers using pattern?

Tags: html

Hello i have the following input :

`<input type="text" name="morningS" class="morningS" id="morningS"  pattern="[0-23]+,[00|25|50|75]$"/>`

im trying to limit it to something like this :
"the numbers before the ',' should be between 0 and 23 only and the number after can only be "00" "25" "75" or "50" but the pattern i added isnt working , anyone can help please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to do the trick...

```
<input type="text" name="morningS" class="morningS" id="morningS" required pattern="^[0-23]+,(00|25|50|75)$" title="Format should be 0-23 followed by a comma, then one of 00, 25, 50, or 75"/>
```

Essentially I just changed the square brackets to regular ones. I also added a title attribute to enable browsers that support it to describe the required pattern to users.

Comment: this doesnt work for a lot of values idk why like : "8,25" "9,25" do u have any idea where the prob is ? :c

Comment: Take 2! `pattern="^([0-9]|[1][0-9]|2[0-3]),(00|25|50|75)$"` - turns out number ranges aren't possible in regex's (understandable as they are designed for matching strings not numbers). The first part of this regex checks for any number between 0 and 9, or 10-19, or 20-23